# Inserting values in table using procedure SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to insert values in Schedule table which looks like that :

```
ID          int         Unchecked
TeacherID   int         Unchecked
SubjectID   int         Unchecked
DayID       int         Unchecked
Time        varchar(5)  Unchecked
StatusID    int         Unchecked
```

Also have Teacher ,Subject and Days table where I store information about teachers like name, surname... it looks like :

```
ID          int             Unchecked
FirstName   nvarchar(50)    Unchecked
LastName    nvarchar(50)    Unchecked
Mobile      int             Unchecked
IDNumber    varchar(11)     Unchecked
StatusID    int             Unchecked
```

here is Subject table

```
ID          int             Unchecked
Name        nvarchar(50)    Unchecked
StatusID    int             Unchecked
```

here is Days table

```
ID      int             Unchecked
Name    nvarchar(15)    Unchecked
```

Want to make a procedure with parameters :

```
@FirstName NVARCHAR(50),
@LastName NVARCHAR(50),
@Subject NVARCHAR(50),
@Day NVARCHAR(15),
@Time VARCHAR(5),
@StatusID INT
```

So the procedure shall take Teacher ID from Teacher's table, Subject table, Days table and insert them alongside other parameters.

I dont know if it is possible or not to do with procedure. Suggest other ways too please.

ID Columns are increment types.

Comment: I can see the point of looking up teacher and subject but not days - what can the days table contribute that you are not passing in a parameter?

Comment: Why don't you pass in the `Id` from `Teacher` and `Subject` tables instead of the names?

Comment: This is possible but FirstName and LastName must be a unique combination or you would end up having multiple TeacherID inserted in one go if two Teachers have same first name and last name.

Comment: @P.Salmon You are partly right, Days table has 7 values inserted, (weekDays), their ID s are ints and are made as key type, so any time i want to insert a day in some tables I insert it's ID, I think it's just a better way. (getting rid of the same NVARCHAR type entries).

Comment: But you are passing dayid and id as paremeters anyway.

Comment: @Mazhar
Going to call the procedure from c#, I need it for some WindowsApp, where user enters the name, last name ... information, then clicks save button ... so just couldnt think of better way.

Comment: @P.Salmon My mistake, edited the question.

Comment: @დავითჯანჯალია A teacher and subject rows must already exist before creating a schedule record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create index iSubj on Subjects (Name) include (ID);
create index iDays on Days (Name) include (ID)
create index iSched on Schedules (TeacherID, SubjectID, DayID, Time, StatusID) include (ID)


create proc InsertSchedule @FirstName varchar(50), @LastName varchar(50), @Subject varchar(50), @Day varchar(15), @Time varchar(5), @StatusID int as begin

insert Schedule (TeacherID, SubjectID, DayID, Time, StatusID)
select distinct t.ID, s.ID, d.ID, @Time, @StatusID
from Teachers t
    inner join Subjects s on s.Name = @Subject
    inner join Days d on d.Name = @Day
    left join Schedule sch (nolock) on sch.TeacherID = t.ID
        and sch.SubjectID = s.ID
        and sch.DayID = d.ID
        and sch.Time = @Time
        and sch.StatusID = @StatusID
where t.FirstName = @FirstName
    and t.LastName = @LastName
    and sch.ID is null

if @@rowcount > 1 print 'Warning: Duplicate Teachers, Subjects, or Days detected'

end
```

I don't know what your data looks like, but I'd also suggest researching:

- Date, Time, and DateTime types
- DateName and DatePart functions
- Renaming @FirstName and @LastName to reflect that it's the *teacher's* name
- Dropping the Days table, unless you have a super-good reason for not just putting a Date  and/or DateTime column in Schedule.
- Selecting a Teacher from a dropdown in your UI and passing the TeacherID in instead.  Ditto for Subjects; and Days, if you can't make Days a "proper" type.